# замена, вставка начального символа построчно в txt

Tags: c#

как выполнить такой алгоритм?
прочитать файл, удалить первый символ во всех строках.
добавить новый символ в начало строки(каждой строки)

Comment: Так и делайте: "прочитать файл, удалить первый символ во всех строках. добавить новый символ в начало строки(каждой строки)". Какой именно пункт вызывает затруднения? Вы пытались писать код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, как-то так:

```
string temppath = path + ".temp";
File.WriteAllLines(temppath,
    File.ReadLines(path)
        .Select(line => line == "" ? "" : 'Ы' + line.Substring(1)));
File.Delete(path);
File.Move(temppath, path);
```

На месте не получится влёгкую, так как Unicode.

Comment: как мне прописать такое: есть 5 строк, каждая строка начинается с разной буквы, надо чтобы софт выводил только ту строку, первая буква которой совпадает с буквой с тхт файле на раб столе, то есть строка если строка начинается с буквы zapadlo(первая буква z) а у меня в тхт первая буква строки k, то эта строка(zapadlo) опказыватся не будет, а будет показана  только та которая начинается с  буквы d в тхт слово dinamo, как-то так

Comment: @May_be: Не совсем понятно. может, приведите пример? Буква из файла на рабочем столе — имеется в виду, любая буква? Первая буква любой строки? (В общем, лучше пример.)

Comment: может быть в лс обсудим ?)) На публику как-то кхм кхммм

Comment: @May_be: Можно, но я завтра буду скорее всего малодоступен. Сейчас создам чат.

Comment: @May_be: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38762/room-for-may-be-and-vladd